# Run async code in nextjs component without using UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my nextjs app, I have a `StrapiImage` component that accepts an image object from my strapi backend api as a prop. It assigns the width, height and url + any aditional props. (It's basically a shortcut for a regular next/image)

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import { getStrapiMedia } from "../../lib/media";

export default function StrapiImage({ image, ...props })
    return <Image src={getStrapiMedia(image)} // the getStrapiMedia function basically just returns the url to the image.
                  width={image.attributes.width}
                  height={image.attributes.height}
                  alt=""
                  {...props} />
}
```

Now, I wanted to add a blur placeholder for this image using `placeholder="blur"` but since this is an external image, I have to provided a base64 image in the `blurDataUrl` prop.

I wanted to generate an image like this with the `plaiceholder` library similarly to this [sollution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18858#issuecomment-862082424) I found.

There's a problem with this though, to generate the image, I need to use an await statement. In `getStaticProps`, this wouldn't be a problem as I could just make the function `async`, but I'm doing this inside a component and components must regular non-async functions.

The 'obvious' sollution would be to use the `useEffect` hook like so:

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import { getStrapiMedia } from "../../lib/media";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getPlaiceholder } from "plaiceholder";

export default function StrapiImage({ image, ...props })
    const [blur64, setBlur64]
    useEffect(() => {
        async function generatePlaceholder() {
            // generate base64 image here
        }
        generatePlaceholder();
    }, [])
    return <Image src={getStrapiMedia(image)}
                  width={image.attributes.width}
                  height={image.attributes.height}
                  alt=""
                  placeholder="blur"
                  blurDataURL={blur64}
                  {...props} />
}
```

This would technically work, but it would only run only on the client-side, ultimately defeating the purpose of ssr and the whole image optimisation. (Especially considering plaiceholder's huge js bundle)

Is there any other way that I could do this without `useEffect` but still in the component file? Ideally, I'd like it to run only on the server-side.

I'm using `nextjs@13`

Comment: If the data is static, fetch it in ```getStaticProps```. All the api calls here.. if you needed while build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using a strapi [plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-placeholder) to generate the placeholder image on the backend rather than on the frontend.

The issue in the title still remains unsolved though. Running pre-renderable async code at component-level doesn't seem to be officialy supported by nextjs. (with the pages directory)

Here's some "sollutions" I've found: (mostly workarounds)

- Generate the placeholders on page-level. For me, that would mean looping through all elements in my api data looking for images and generating placeholders for them. It's pretty inconvenient but it does work.
- Switch to the app directory. (provided you're using next 13) It uses react server components so all of this is possible and simple to do there.
- Try to work with `useSSE`. I haven't looked into this too much but it looks like you can use the `useSSE` library to run server-side at component-level. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@A__G__B/component-level-data-fetching-in-next-js-with-srr-8d35cdc5849e) covering this.